# SQL Access Inner Join If First Letter are the Same

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

```
SELECT 
    a.adjective,  b.animal
FROM 
    sec1309_table1 AS a, sec1309_table2 AS b
WHERE 
    a.adjective = b.animal
ORDER BY 
    b.animal;
```

Also this is a query not a table see my picture and thank you for the help!

(I guess the a.(dot) and b.(dot) as in a.adjective is the first and second columns)

I'm trying to get these two tables called `sec1309_table1` and `sec1309_table2` into one table with a join  "adjective" is the one column in the first table and "animal"

The contents of the table are like this

```
adjective    |  animal
-------------------------   
apple           Ape
blue            buck
red             rooster
```

id like to join by first letter of string like  (without all the duplicates in my pic)

Joined query

```
apple ape
blue  buck
red   rooster
```

http://i1173.photobucket.com/albums/r596/rubyandrobin/joinbyFirstString_zps9f806a23.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LEFT` function to get the first letter when defining your join:

```
SELECT a.adjective, b.animal
FROM sec1309_table1 AS a
INNER JOIN sec1309_table2 AS b ON LEFT(a.adjective, 1) = LEFT(b.animal, 1)
order by b.animal;
```